# BMC Remedy User (WMSTI): Macro Language?

Tags: macros, wms, remedy

I need to know the language, which is used in BMC Remedy User (WMSTI) macros? The tool is called '*BMC Remedy User*' (WMS-TI within the company (Telekom)).

Here are some code snippets from the macros which are standardly implemented:

```
Form-open: 
Form-entry-list: 0
Form-final: modify@
end
```

and another snippet:

```
[wordrecord]
Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\winword.exe
Application=winword
Topic=system
Format=Record
CharsPerLine=100
XFRDATA=Clipboard
Command1=[FileNew .Template="Normal", .NewTemplate = 0]
Command2=[Editpaste]
```

What kind of language is this and is there any learning material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remedy User Tool **macro** language is proprietary.

Since Remedy User Tool is not supported anymore, I'd encourage you to use updated technologies, like SOAP or REST (for everything back-end), or AngularJS (for everything front-end)

Another solution would be to use tools created by the Remedy Community, like the one appearing on https://communities.bmc.com/message/437693#437693

Answer (score 1):

BMC Remedy User tool is not supported but developer can install it locally to ease their work.
apart from this, have a look on-https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-28466